# Placement of Code in Plugin for hooking `save_post`

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, hooks, save-post

I ran into a strange Problem today developing a new Plugin.

I set it up as usual, creating the `f711-roomprice` folder in the Plugindirectory, and creating the `f711-roomprice.php` as well as an `inc` directory in there.

Everything worked fine with the activation hook and the included functions, until i created an include:

```
include('inc/filter-savepost.php');
```

this file contained the following code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'f711_roomprice_meta_box_save' );  
function f711_roomprice_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {

    if( !isset( $_POST['f711_roomprice_prices'] ) ) return;

    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 

    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'f711_roomprice_box_nonce' ) ) return; 

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    foreach( $_POST['f711_roomprice_prices'] as $room => $seasons ) {
        foreach( $seasons as $season => $price ) {

            f711_roomprice_insert( $room, $season, $price );

        }

    }

}
```

After including the file in my main plugin file, I got an Error resulting in a white screen on Saving a post, everything else worked fine.

The function `f711_roomprice_meta_box_save` is called, confirmed this with an `wp_die('f711_roomprice_meta_box_saveis called')` in there.

Now the strangest thing is, i placed the code (exactly the same as in the include file) in my main Plugin file, and skipped the include of course. Now it works just as I want it to.

I also tried just adding the `save_post` action in the main Plugin file and including the function from `inc/filter-savepost.php`, still got the wrong result as before.

What am I doing wrong here? Is the placement of the Code (Hooks, Functions) really important in a Plugin, or is it just something on my part gone wrong?

Comment: Is debug on? Is it showing any messages?

Comment: Yep, had debug on - showed some information about a fancyboxplugin i used. Funny thing, I deactivated all other Plugins, and it worked with the include. How can this affect the way I use my plugin? I call the exact same functions as before, just from a different file.

Comment: Try deactivating fancyboxplugin only?

Comment: Yeah, that was the bad one. But nevertheless, I don't get why this affected my Plugin in a way that I needed to change the file structure. That's the odd thing..

Comment: Send me the plugin link i will check it out.

Comment: Is just in the raw development (Version 0.1 started today), so I don't have anything ready. Thanks for the help so far - I will post something about it if I find out what was wrong :)

Comment: `current_user_can( 'edit_post'` seems strange to me, I think it should be `current_user_can( 'edit_posts'` but if in the main file works this make no sense...

Comment: @fischi Is this already solved?

Comment: @kaiser i made a workaround to develop the plugin for my customer, but the error still puzzles me. for the matter of WordPressSE, I think the topic could be closed, although I do not have a solution or more detailled description of the problem.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Tried to set the current user manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing through my old questions, I reopened this one and tested some things out in my plugin.

The solution was quite simple, although I am not sure if it had something to do with a new version of WordPress as well.

I refactored the plugin and noticed different encodings than last time I tested this. I don't know how I did not recognize this. Now, everything being `UTF-8 without BOM`, and nicely structured into different files (as it was planned), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if

```
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;
```

really works. Maybe the current user isn't set up there and you'll have to work around it by passing the user ID in a hidden field, then retrieving it using

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', esc_attr( $_POST['user_id'] ) );
wp_set_current_user( $user->user_id );
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )
    wp_die( 'Not allowed' );
```